# How to obtain the frame buffer from within QWidget's paintEvent()

Tags: qt

Is there any way to get the pixels that will be displayed on a QWidget, do some processing, and then display the processed pixels?

I can't seem to overcome the limitations of paintEvent(), hopefully someone can help.

QPixmap::grabWidget and QWidget::render will get me the pixels I need, but they cannot be called from within paintEvent(), since doing so will trigger an infinite loop.

I have tried running a timer, taking a snapshot, doing my processing, forcing a repaint, and displaying the saved image.  This works to some extent, but on dynamic content (i.e. moving) it fails miserably.

I need to be able to do this from within paintEvent().

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your problem would be best solved by rendering the widget to a pixmap (within the paint event), doing your processing on the pixmap, then rendering the result to the widget afterwards:

```
void MySuperAwesomeWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
   QPixmap pixmap(size());
   QPainter painter;

   painter.begin(&pixmap);
   // Drawing code goes here
   painter.end();

   // Do processing on pixmap here

   painter.begin(this);
   painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap);
   painter.end();
}
```

Normally, the technique I've described would be considered unnecessary (or even undesirable) because it is essentially a form of double-buffering and `QWidget` [already provides double-buffering](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#transparency-and-double-buffering) behind the scenes.  However, in your case you are doing some processing on the drawing before performing a final rendering.  As such, this is probably the best approach.

Comment: Thanks.  This is very close to what I need.  However, I am not looking to draw the widget's content here, only modify it with my image processing algorithm.  I am actually using a subclassed QDeclarativeView to render QML content, but I need to postfilter it immediately before it goes out to the screen.

Comment: Well, it looks like I can perform a render() inside of the first painter.begin(&pixmap)...painter.end() block, which will do exactly what I need.  Thanks again!